# SQL query order by and limit taking a lot of time

Tags: sql, postgresql, backend

I am querying a table with around 4M data with two types of skuID and using order by on version as there are around avg 5k versions of data for one skuID and fetching the top most versions using limit.

**Query:**

```
 select * FROM table rb 
    WHERE rb.sku_id='' or rb.package_sku_id=''
    order by version desc
limit 1;
```

By using explain on query we found out that ORDER BY and LIMIT is taking most of the cost for the query:

```
Limit  (cost=0.43..5304.64 rows=1 width=861) (actual time=50327.036..50327.041 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=361280 read=104302 written=18
  I/O Timings: read=40363.693 write=0.215
  ->  Index Scan Backward using "IDX488yr43nr28a1yml9lb5i7jfv" on referral_benefits rb  (cost=0.43..9552890.48 rows=1801 width=861) (actual time=50327.028..50327.028 rows=1 loops=1)
        Filter: (((sku_id)::text = 'b1d5fa77-fda8-466c-b8b0-a8e60d1f78a5'::text) OR ((package_sku_id)::text = 'b1d5fa77-fda8-466c-b8b0-a8e60d1f78a5'::text))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 1361027
        Buffers: shared hit=361280 read=104302 written=18
        I/O Timings: read=40363.693 write=0.215
Planning Time: 1.121 ms
Execution Time: 50329.843 ms
```

We have added indexes on skuId and package_sku_id combined but that is not reducing the time.

Need guidance on this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does an index on the 'version' column help at all?

Comment: Have added index on:
-skuId
-package_sku_id
-skuID and package_sku_id
- version
Still this is not helping

Comment: How long is "a lot of time?" Please run the query with `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` and add the results to the question. An isolated line from `EXPLAIN` is not useful.

Comment: @JohnH depending on RDS usage time is varying from 1,500ms - 10,000 ms when usage is high..
Have added full result of explain

Comment: Please run `EXPLAIN (ANALIZE, BUFFERS)` to get **actual** counts and times. Running `EXPLAIN` without options is of limited value.

Comment: @JohnH added analize and buffer result

Comment: Please post the DDL for the table and its indexes.

Comment: "We have added indexes on skuId and package_sku_id combined but that is not reducing the time."  Please show the actual definition, not just some hand-waving.

Comment: "By using explain on query we found out that sorting is taking most of the cost for the query"  That plan doesn't even have a sort in it!

Comment: @jjanes by sorting i meant ORDER BY, as sorting is involved executing order by.., have mentioned that in description.

Comment: In this case, the ordering is provided by the index, not directly by sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two indexes, one on `(sku_id, version)` and one on `(package_sku_id, version)`, then you could get very fast execution by doing:

```
(select * FROM rb WHERE rb.sku_id='b1d5fa77-fda8-466c-b8b0-a8e60d1f78a5' order by version desc) 
    union all
(select * FROM rb WHERE rb.package_sku_id='b1d5fa77-fda8-466c-b8b0-a8e60d1f78a5' order by version desc)
order by version desc limit 1;
```

But note that if you increase the LIMIT beyond 1, then this query might return duplicate rows if both SKU conditions are satisfied for the same row.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL features partial indexes, i.e. indexes that only apply to a subset of the table. Use that index type and have it only contain the rows you want to look at. Then the DBMS only has to read that index and the data comes out sorted:

```
create index idx on mytable (version desc)
                 where sku_id = '' or package_sku_id = '';
```

Another option would be a separate table only containing the desired top row. Write a trigger to keep that up-to-date.